# Conditional lazy-loading with Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js comes with support for [component lazy-loading](https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components/#lazy-loading-your-components), by prefixing the component name with `lazy-`. But is there anyway to conditionally lazy-load, short of duplicating the code with `v-if/else`?

E.g. something like this?

```html
<list :lazy="shouldBeLazyLoaded">
   ...some complex markup
</list>
```

Currently I do it like this:

```html
<lazy-list v-if="shouldBeLazyLoaded">
   ...some complex markup
</lazy-list>
<list v-else>
   ...some complex markup
<list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your could use [Vue's dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for this:

```html
<component v-bind:is="shouldBeLazyLoaded ? 'lazy-list' : 'list'">
  ...some complex markup
</component>
```

Comment: That's a neat idea, but unfortunately Nuxt does not seem to be able to pick up the lazy-prefix, so at least as of Nuxt 2.15, this does not work.